# How to setup a data sync micro-services with a Message Queue

Tags: synchronization, message-queue, microservices

I am currently building a system (SaaS-like) which is running with micro-services and larger services (due to various constraints) which will be used by multiple clients (e.g. multiple accounts), part of the core system requires data from other systems (e.g. The Client's systems) to be in the core systems database. I will manage this through having a sync micro-service which on a set time will call the other systems API(s) and process the data, apply it into the core database and mark any specific changes in state into a message queue for other services to then process.

My core problem is that if I have multiple clients with multiple sync jobs and multiple sync services (e.g. 2+ sync service apps) how will I manage the jobs so that two syncs don't operate at once and the services all operate on mixed client systems etc. Overall the aim is be to able to scale easily.

So far the options I have come up with are:

1. Use basic cron job and set a sync service to a single client (unable to scale easy)
2. Use another service to put items into a MQ for the sync services to pick it up (the other service cannot scale)
3. Use a AWS system such as Cloud Watch to push into MQ and multiple sync services work from the queue

Has anyone come up with this problem before? Whats a good option or recommendation?

*Technology dependent answers are fine, but the services are built on Node.js and using a mySQL database.*

Answer (score 0):

One of the way would be that timer job will put the data into message queue and there are multiple listeners on the queue (which is partitioned based on some id) and you scale by increasing the listeners.

Mostly this should suffice.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So do you mean, we have a timer service, putting items into message queue for the sync workers to pickup then process? Whats the best way to ensure high redundancy on the timer service?